# Java Custom thread pool not terminating

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I am trying to implement a simple thread pool in java. I have used a shutdown method to shut down the thread using an isActive flag. But the worker threads never seem to shutdown.
Please help me to find the bug in this implementation.

```
 import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class CustomThreadPool {
    private WorkerThread[] threads;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
    public CustomThreadPool(int threadNumber){
        taskQueue=new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        threads=new WorkerThread[threadNumber];
        System.out.println(threadNumber);
        for(int i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
            threads[i]=new WorkerThread();
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void submit(Runnable task){
        synchronized (taskQueue){
            System.out.println("added to queue");
            taskQueue.add(task);
            taskQueue.notify();
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
        for(WorkerThread worker : threads){
            worker.shutdown();
            worker.join();
        }
    }

    private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
        boolean isActive=true;
        public void run() {
            while(isActive) {
                Runnable task;
                try {
                    task=taskQueue.take();
                    System.out.println("took task from queue");
                    task.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void shutdown(){
            isActive=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: Why are you reinventing the wheel, instead of using Java [thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)?  Q: Are you sure that each thread is checking `isActive` in a timely manner?  Why don't you mark it `volatile`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: But even if you make `isActive` volatile, you'd still be blocked on the `take()` call. You should interrupt the thread as well.

Comment: Is it possible to complete the task before interrupting the worker ?

Comment: @AndyTurner, Re, "...blocked on the take() call." That is easily fixed. Change the `shutdown()` method to stuff as many trivial tasks into the queue as the number of worker threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, a "poison pill" could work. For anyone implementing such a solution, an important detail is that the worker thread must be able to detect that the trivial task is a shutdown signal and then terminate; otherwise one of the threads could consume all of the trivial tasks.

Answer (score 0):

-Declare isActive as volatile so WorkerThread can see new value.

-Change take() to poll() so the thread can have a chance to check the value of isActive

Comment: Don't change `take()` to `poll()`. Instead, stuff a bunch of do-nothing tasks into the queue so that the worker `take()` calls all will return something.

Comment: @Don Ha - I don't want to mark you down - but Solomon Slow is correct: "poll()" is a Bad Idea :(  Please consider changing your response.  Frankly, maybe a good old-fashioned "stop()" might even be better than "isActive"...  But Java 8 is so rich in concurrency enhancements - I'd vote for the OP to redesign the whole thing :)

Comment: I agree poll is a bad idea, but without rewriting the whole thing, that is that only easy fix to answer the original question.